# Disable/stop event on HOME button pressed AOSP

Tags: java, android, android-source

How can I disable/stop the event when the HOME button is pressed?

Setup:

- **AOSP 4.4**
- **Nexus 5**
- This is for a custom ROM so I can modify anything in the AOSP code

Comment: I am not sure if such thing ever existed, even in costume ROMs.

Comment: @bluebrain since I have access to the entire AOSP, there should be ANY way of disabling the button/event/intent I assume

Comment: What are you wanting to do? Just prevent the home button from doing anything?

Answer (score 0):

You could disable the home button, but it might be difficult to navigate without a home button.

In case you just want to disable home button because of some application that you are running, 
there might be easier ways to do so, like setting your application as a homescreen and overriding the home button.

To disable a button in android.
You could try commenting it out in the keylayout

Refer: https://source.android.com/devices/tech/input/key-layout-files.html